# Integers and string in a prepared statement

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I have this in my try clause... It is working fine if I remove `pst.setString(5, value5)`,
also it works if I remove all the integer values, but I can't get it to work if all the integers and value5 is added...

```
try {
  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "username", "password");
  String sql ="UPDATE table1 SET value1 = ?, value2 = ?, value3 = ?, value4 = ? value5 = ? WHERE value6 = ? ";
  PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

  Integer value1A = Integer.parseInt(value1),
  value2A = Integer.parseInt(value2),
  value2A = Integer.parseInt(value3),
  value2A = Integer.parseInt(value4);  

  pst.setInt(1, value1A);
  pst.setInt(2, value2A);
  pst.setInt(3, value3A);
  pst.setInt(4, value4A);
  pst.setString(5, value5);
  pst.setString(6, value6);

  int numRowsChanged = pst.executeUpdate();

  pst.close();
}
```

Comment: Please also post the exception you are getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a comma in your `SQL`:

```
String sql ="UPDATE table1 SET value1 = ?, value2 = ?, value3 = ?, value4 = ?, value5 = ? WHERE value6 = ? ";
                                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are missing a comma?